# Aligning x-axis labels with Bars in MpAndroidChart BarChart in Android

Tags: java, android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I would like to align the labels of my x-axis with the bars in my bar chart.

When launching the graph, only 3 of the 5 labels appear, as can be seen in this image [image].

As soon as I zoom in slightly, the rest of the labels appear, as can be seen in this image [image: here]

The following is the relevant code relating to the building of the Bar Graph and its x-axis:

```
            for (int c = 0; c < numberOfStoriesPlayed; c++) {
                barEntries.add(new BarEntry(chartData [0] [c], chartData [1] [c]));
            }

            BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Social Stories");


            XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
            xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
            xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisLabel));


            BarData data;
            data = new BarData(barDataSet);


            barChart.setData(data);
            barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
            barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
            barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
            barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
            barChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
            barChart.setDragEnabled(true);
            barChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
            barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
            barChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            barChart.invalidate();
            barChart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);
```

I would like to find a way for all labels to show up immediately, and not just when I start zooming, and also for them to be properly aligned with the bars in the graph. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share IndexAxisValueFormatter?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir this is a built in class which is part of MpANdroidChart

Comment: Can you try to use "c" instead of "chartData [0] [c]"